# Lines and Planes in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the symmetric equations for two lines lying in the same plane, how do I determine the equation of that plane?
I tried finding the intersection point of the two lines, and the cross product of the two position vectors, but I am uncertain where to proceed.

Comment: What do you mean by "symmetric equations?" Can you give an example?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. The vocabulary in your question is confusing. If you [edit] the question to post an example and your work we may be able to help.

Comment: What do you know about the equation of any plane?